# In my JDBC project, always if condition returns false

Tags: java, jdbc

this is my service

I tried in various ways,but it always returns `false` when comparing strings inside a `if` condition, `if(pwd==dbpw)` is also return `false`, every time like this code.

```
    public boolean authenticate(String email,String pwd){

        boolean result=false;
        String dbpw="";
        DBConnect myDB=new DBConnect();

        Connection con=myDB.getConnection();

        try {
            Statement mySt=con.createStatement();
            //ResultSet myRes=mySt.executeQuery("select pwd from admin where email=\'"+email+"\'");
            ResultSet myRes=mySt.executeQuery("select pwd from admin where email=\'sankasumadura@gmail.com\'");


            while(myRes.next()){
            dbpw=myRes.getString("pwd");
            }



            if(pwd.equals(dbpw)){
                result=true;
            }else{
                result=false;
            }



        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
                }
        finally{


                return result;
                }





    }
```

I try with more inputs, but always output is false, But database retrieve correct value and,that problem occurs when comparing inside a `if` condition.
please help  me.

Comment: just to be sure if it is a whitespace or lower/upper case problem try: if(pwd.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(dbpw.trim())){

Comment: What values for `pwd` and `dbpw` do you see when you print them out just before your comparison?

Comment: Or put a logging line into your code to see the content of the variables, e.g. `log.debug("pwd = [{}], dbpw = [{}]", pwd, dbpw);` (or `System.out.println("pwd = [" + pwd + "], dbpw = [" + dbpw + "]");` if you don't have a Log instance).

Comment: Btw. it is **DEFINITELY BAD IDEA** to store plaintext passwords in the DB. Passwords *must* be hashed, e.g. using [BCrypt](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-password-hashing-example/).

Comment: It is run corectly when 'trim()' string objects, thank you very much

Comment: it is working, thank you @Stefan Beike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check  your viraible contains the whitespace :

```
pwd=request.getParameter("pwd").toString().trim();
```

before return, you can print the value to your console:

```
System.out.println("pwd:" + pwd + ",dbpw:" + dbpw + ",isequal:" + pwd.equals(dbpw));
if (pwd.equals(dbpw)) {
    result = true;
} else {
    result = false;
}
```